# Binary Search Tree Validation

Tags: c#

Thank you for reading my topic. I am practising a little bit with C# at **Test Dome**. The exercise I am currently trying to program is the following:
http://www.testdome.com/Questions/Csharp/BinarySearchTree/484?testId=21&testDifficulty=Hard

**My current result:**

- Example case: Correct answer
- Simple cases: Correct answer
- Regular cases: Wrong answer
- Edge cases: Wrong answer
- Performance test: Wrong answer

You can read the code I wrote so far below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }                      // Value of {node} == integer (1,2,3,4,5)
    public Node Left { get; set; }                      // Reference to left node (n1, n2, n3) == Node.
    public Node Right { get; set; }                     // Reference to right node (n1, n2, n3) == Node.
    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right)       
    {
        Value = value;                                  // (int)
        Left = left;                                    // (node)
        Right = right;                                  // (node)
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree
{
    public static bool IsValidBST(Node root)
    {
        if (root.Left == null && root.Right == null)
            return true;

        else if (root.Left == null)
        {
            // Checking root.Right.Value
            if (root.Value <= root.Right.Value)
                return true;

            else
                return false;
        }
        else if (root.Right == null)
        {
            // Checking root.Left.Value
            if (root.Value > root.Left.Value)
                return true;
            else
                return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            // Checking both Values
            if (root.Value > root.Left.Value && root.Value <= root.Right.Value)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n1 = new Node(1, null, null);
        Node n3 = new Node(3, null, null);
        Node n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);

        // Execute function and write it to the console
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidBST(n2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to implement to pass the test. I don't want you to give me written-code, but more information about the exercice. Keep in mind that my current-code is far from neat. Thank you all.

Comment: See my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625016/how-to-find-a-node-implement-method-contains-in-a-binary-search-tree-bst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check those other nodes `root.Left` and `root.Right` by calling `IsValidBST` on them if they are not `null` and then checking these results. Right now you only test the root node instead of descending into the tree

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking all upper nodes values. You should have array/list of all upper nodes, so you can check it.

And also you should use recursion call.
Like this

```
IsValidBST(Node root, List<int> upperValues = null) 
{
 ... 
 bool childIsValid = IsValidBST (root.Left, upperValuesLeft ) && IsValidBST(root.Right, upperValuesRight )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer code:

```
if (root.Value == value) return true;

if (root.Left != null && value < root.Value)
    if (Contains(root.Left, value)) return true;

if (root.Right != null && value > root.Value)
    if (Contains(root.Right, value)) return true;

return false;
```

Read [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625016/how-to-find-a-node-implement-method-contains-in-a-binary-search-tree-bst) of the same question.